# adding row in datagridview programmatically on checkedlistbox.check and delete same on uncheck

Tags: c#, ado.net, datagridview

im having a code a problem with the code.i have a checkedlistbox with 12 months in it..i have a datagridview where i have to display the fees for each month already described in the database.when i select 'june' from checkedlistbox it should retrieve all columns of table where month is june, and when i uncheck the same it should rollback(remove dat particular row)
I have a code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string strCon = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SAHS;User Id=sa;Password=faculty";
        string strSQL = "select mnthname as 'Month',Description,Amount from monthfee";

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, strCon);
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

        // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        dataAdapter.Fill(table);
        bindingSource1.DataSource = table;

        // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.

        dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
        // you can make it grid readonly.
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
        // finally bind the data to the grid
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strCon = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SAHS;User Id=sa;Password=faculty";
        string strSQL = "select mnthname as 'Month',Description,Amount from monthfee where mnthname='" + checkedListBox1.Text + "'";

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, strCon);
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

        // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        dataAdapter.Fill(table);
        bindingSource1.DataSource = table;

        // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.

        dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
        // you can make it grid readonly.
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
        // finally bind the data to the grid
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        }
    }
}
```

when i run this it works fine but the problem is when i select 'june' it shows june and when i select 'july' it overwrites june n shows july,it should add row july,and when i uncheck 'july' it should remove row 'july' n same for 'june'..
plss help srry for anything wrongly explained.

Comment: Since you have all the data in the datatable why not filter it there and then assign the source, instead of querying it again and again

Comment: can you please show how.i feel there is a need for addrow property n instead select query use insert . but i tried im getting errors.im a newbie so cant get through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not using the `selecteditems` in the `checkedListBox1`. So that means that you are assigning the new datasource that contains all or just one Month. And I can not see why you have duplicate your code first in the constructor of the `Form()` and then again on the `checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`. Here is a suggestion:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindGrid();
}
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGrid();
}
private void BindGrid()
{
    CheckedListBox  checkedListBox1=new CheckedListBox();
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    foreach (ListBox item in checkedListBox1.SelectedItems)
    {
        sb.Append("'"+item.Text+"',");
    }
    if(sb.Length>0)
        sb.Length--;

    string strSQL;
    if(sb.Length>0)
    {
        strSQL = "select mnthname as 'Month',Description,Amount from monthfee where mnthname IN(" + sb.ToString()+ ")";
    }
    else
    {
        strSQL = "select mnthname as 'Month',Description,Amount from monthfee";
    }
    string strCon = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SAHS;User Id=sa;Password=faculty";
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, strCon);
    SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

    // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    dataAdapter.Fill(table);
    bindingSource1.DataSource = table;

    // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.

    dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
    // you can make it grid readonly.
    dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
    // finally bind the data to the grid
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
}
```

Comment: it is showing me an error ..
The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).where should i declare string var .

Comment: @HMcompfreak : Remember to upvote if you think the answer is good. It gives us all warm-fuzzy feelings :P